# Send Command using AVRCP Bluetooth Profile - Android

Tags: bluetooth, avrcp

I need to know, if I can send Bluetooth AVRCP command using BluetoothAvrcontrollerService from an android app to a hardware which supports AVRCP profile in Bluetooth. If it is possible please provide a sample for the same. Thanks in advance.